# Does reset Windows 10 procedure removes user account

Tags: windows-10

I understand that Reset Windows 10 procedure offers to store or delete user files but what happens to the user account? Nobody states that.

If I have a user account on my PC named Joe and perform a reset and choose option to keep user files will this account survive the reset ( I will be able to login using that account into OS ) or not?

Comment: In order to answer this question, you must indicate which option you selected, with regards to your personal files.  Windows 10 Reset functionality reinstalls Windows, so it goes through the same steps, understanding what option you choose will help us answer your question.  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that Reset Windows 10 procedure offers to store or delete user files but what happens to the user account?

When you perform a Reset Windows 10 is reinstalled.  Depending on which option you select with regards to your personal files determines if your user profiles are migrated or not.  If you choose to keep all your personal files, during the installation process, Windows will migrate your user profile to the new installation.  This is the same process that is used to upgrade your Windows 10 installation to a new version of Windows 10 when a feature update is released.

> If I have a user account on my PC named Joe and perform a reset and choose the option to keep user files will this account survive the reset ( I will be able to login using that account into OS ) or not?

All personal files contained within your user profile's directory will be migrated to the new installation.  The credentials for this migrated user profile will be exactly the same.

> I was asking would I be able to login using same credentials into OS or not. Everybody just repeats the stuff about the files being migrated.

Yes; If you choose to keep your personal files, your user profile will be migrated to the new Windows installation, which means the same credentials will be used.

Comment: @DarkoMiletic - Despite the fact my original answer absolutely addressed that specific concern (within the first paragraph), I have added a second paragraph that addresses it specifically, and says in no uncertain terms that your user profile will be migrated to the new installation.  *The fact the first paragraph answers your question isn’t up for debate.*

Answer (score 0):

During the reset, if you choose to keep all your data, your user profile will be kept and you can log in with the same user profile. I have done this myself.

If you choose to Keep Nothing, the user profile will not be kept.  I have done this as well.